# Two tanks - draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a TIKZ beginner  going to make some maths notes and appreciate very much if someone could draw(designe/program) for me a two tanks system like this:

[image: Sketch]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which is the specific problem here? We got more than 3300 TikZ questions with answers here, perhaps browse around to see how to draw cylinders, arrows, and more. Not to mention the great TikZ manual. It would be good if you would show what you could already achieve and then post a real question. As it stands, the question may be closed as too localized. However, it can be reopened if it was edited and improved. Or edit it right away. We answer questions and gladly help to solve problems. It's just not a drawing service. ;-)

Comment: You can draw it in Inkscape and export it as TikZ. The exported code should provide you with some insights on TikZ's structure.

Comment: Thank you for both answer. I downloaded Inkscape and extensions. But I have not used drawing programes before and it takes time to get used to draw pictures with 3D effects. I am finishing a maths book and should focus on the writing. Thank you any way. I just hope somebody gets time to help me here. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: do you want it to look 'hand drawn' (as in your picture), or would you be interested in a 'straight-line' (much easier!) approach?

Comment: Dear cmhughes, No it can look like such a format:http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/docs/demos/twotanks.php

Comment: Water can be light grey. I wish also to change the values later. So if it is a Tikz code, I can change. If it is handdrawn: Water inn tank 1 : v1 - Water out in tank 2: v2 and the water velocities between tanks v3 (from tank 1 to 2) and v4 (frpm tank 2 to 1). Thanks in advance:)

Comment: or like this http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/EngMath_DifferentialEquation.html#Mixing_Problem_2   Please remember v1, v2, v3 and v4 are written like v_1 (1 is index)

Answer (score 13):

Here's something to get you started

[image: screenshot]

I'm sure that it could be done far more intelligently, but it does the job :)

I have used the [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) to typeset the units- perhaps this is overkill, but I think it's worth doing these things properly. If you load the [`nicefrac`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/nicefrac) package then you can use `fraction-function = \nicefrac`; experiment as you see fit.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction} %,fraction-function = \nicefrac}
\DeclareSIUnit{\gallon}{gal}

% set the arrows as stealth fighters (personal preference)
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw the tanks
    \draw (0,6)--(0,0)--(3,0)--(3,1)--(4,1)--(4,0)--(6,0)--(6,-1);
    \draw (7,-1)--(7,5)--(4,5)--(4,4)--(3,4)--(3,5)--(1,5)--(1,6);
    % fill them with water (in the background)
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \filldraw[blue!20] (0,4.5)--(3,4.5)--(3,4)% tank 1
                                  --(4,4)         % connection
                                  --(4,4.5)--(7,4.5)--(7,-1)--(6,-1)--(6,0)--(4,0) % tank 2
                                  --(4,1)--(3,1)--(3,0)--(0,0) %back to tank 1
                                  -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % connection piece
    \filldraw[white,draw=black] (3,2)--(3,3)--(4,3)--(4,2)--cycle;
    % add the rates
    \draw[->] (0.5,6)--(0.5,5)node[pos=0,anchor=south west]{\SI{20}{\gallon\per\minute}};
    \draw[->] (6.5,0)--(6.5,-1)node[pos=1,anchor=north]{\SI{20}{\gallon\per\minute}};
    \draw[->] (3,1.5)--(4,1.5)node[anchor=south]{\SI{30}{\gallon\per\minute}};
    \draw[<-] (3,3.5)--(4,3.5)node[anchor=south]{\SI{10}{\gallon\per\minute}};
    \node at (1,1){Tank 1};
    \node at (6,1){Tank 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Personally I prefer simpler diagrams to explain concepts. Can you correct the physics please? Both middle arrows should point to the right.

Comment: Thank you Yiannis, this can be a good start and I try to see if I can make it 3D by using cylinder form tanks instead for rectangle form. I appreciate your assistance:) Have a happy new year!!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides thanks! The current problem serves as a good introduction to systems of differential equations because the tanks mix their contents together- as such, the arrows are pointing in the correct direction (although the bottom 10gal/min should be 30gal/min, will update)

Comment: @cmhughes Aha! I see what you were after. I was thinking more continuity equation.

Comment: @Leopard you're welcome! If your question is solved, you can consider 'accepting' an answer by using the green check mark- welcome :)

Comment: Dear Cmhughes, I can not find the green check mark. Can you please write where I can mark it as accepted? Thanks:)

Comment: @Leopard sure :) The check mark isn't actually green until you click on it (my mistake); you should see one for each answer, but unfortunately you can only accept *one* answer. When you hover over it, it says, 'click this answer to accept it, click again to toggle'; once you've clicked it, it will turn green :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to concentrate on writing and do not have much time to learn PGF/TikZ then GeoGebra is another option.  The following figure (and the associated code) was generated using GeoGebra in about 10 minutes.
[image]

The following is the GeoGebra generated code.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4,-2) rectangle (11,5);
\draw [rotate around={0:(0.5,3)}] (0.5,3) ellipse (1.51cm and 0.19cm);
\draw (-1,3)-- (-1,0);
\draw (2,3)-- (2,0);
\draw [rotate around={0:(0.5,0)}] (0.5,0) ellipse (1.51cm and 0.19cm);
\draw [rotate around={0:(5.5,3)}] (5.5,3) ellipse (1.51cm and 0.19cm);
\draw (4,3)-- (4,0);
\draw (7,3)-- (7,0);
\draw [rotate around={0:(5.5,0)}] (5.5,0) ellipse (1.51cm and 0.19cm);
\draw (-3,4.4)-- (-1,4.4);
\draw (-3,4)-- (-1,4);
\draw [shift={(-1.6,4.2)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(-0.4,4.2)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.46,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw (2,2.4)-- (4,2.4);
\draw (2,2)-- (4,2);
\draw [shift={(3.4,2.2)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(4.6,2.2)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.46,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw (2,1)-- (4,1);
\draw (2,0.6)-- (4,0.6);
\draw [shift={(3.39,0.8)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.64*cos(\t r)+0*0.64*sin(\t r)},{0*0.64*cos(\t r)+1*0.64*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(4.59,0.8)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.47,variable=\t]({1*0.62*cos(\t r)+0*0.62*sin(\t r)},{0*0.62*cos(\t r)+1*0.62*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(1.4,2.2)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(2.6,2.2)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.46,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(1.4,0.8)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(2.6,0.8)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.46,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw (7,1)-- (7.4,1);
\draw (7,0.6)-- (7.4,0.6);
\draw (7.6,0.4)-- (7.6,-0.2);
\draw (8,0.4)-- (8,-0.2);
\draw [shift={(7.4,0.4)}] plot[domain=0:1.57,variable=\t]({1*0.2*cos(\t r)+0*0.2*sin(\t r)},{0*0.2*cos(\t r)+1*0.2*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(7.4,0.4)}] plot[domain=0:1.57,variable=\t]({1*0.6*cos(\t r)+0*0.6*sin(\t r)},{0*0.6*cos(\t r)+1*0.6*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(7.8,0.4)}] plot[domain=4.39:5.03,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(7.8,-0.8)}] plot[domain=1.25:1.89,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(6.4,0.8)}] plot[domain=-0.32:0.32,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(7.6,0.8)}] plot[domain=2.82:3.46,variable=\t]({1*0.63*cos(\t r)+0*0.63*sin(\t r)},{0*0.63*cos(\t r)+1*0.63*sin(\t r)});
\draw (-0.8,4.2)-- (-0.4,4.2);
\draw [->] (-0.2,4) -- (-0.2,3.4);
\draw [shift={(-0.4,4)}] plot[domain=0:1.57,variable=\t]({1*0.2*cos(\t r)+0*0.2*sin(\t r)},{0*0.2*cos(\t r)+1*0.2*sin(\t r)});
\draw [->] (3.4,2.6) -- (2.6,2.6);
\draw [->] (2.6,0.4) -- (3.4,0.4);
\draw [->] (7.8,-0.4) -- (7.8,-1.2);
\draw (-.2,4) node[anchor=north west] {$20 gal/min$};
\draw (2,3.2) node[anchor=north west] {$10 gal/min$};
\draw (2,0.4) node[anchor=north west] {$30 gal/min$};
\draw (8.1,-0.5) node[anchor=north west] {$20 gal/min$};
\draw (0.06,2.29) node[anchor=north west] {$\# 1$};
\draw (5.2,2.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\#2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Can you please fill the tanks with some gray or blue liquid and demonstrating water is flows inn and run out the thanks? Thank you and happy new year to you and  all here!

Comment: And can you please move the pipe from which the water is running out in the lower part of the tank?